# How to place an Image on top of other Image in React Native?

Tags: ios, image, react-native

I placed an Image as a root node in order to make it a background for my View. But it appears that all others image become invisible...
Is it any way to place an image on top of the background using built-in components, without any plugins? 
In the following code sample `landing-background` is used as a background, my `logo` image is visible, but only if background is removed.
`Text` is showing on top of the background without any concerns...

```
    <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image source = {require('./img/landing-background.jpg')}
              resizeMode = 'cover' style = {styles.backdrop}>
              <View style = {styles.overlay}>
                <Text style = {styles.headline}>It should appear in front of the Background Image</Text>
    <Image style = {styles.logo} source = {require('./img/logo.png')} />
              </View>

              </Image>
    </View>

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
      overlay: {
        opacity: 0.5,
        backgroundColor: '#000000'
      },
      logo: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        width: 160,
        height: 52
      },
      backdrop: {
        flex:1,
        flexDirection: 'column'
      },
      headline: {
        fontSize: 18,
        textAlign: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        color: 'white'
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Rather than wrapping your content in the `<Image>`, I think you would be better off wrapping that in an `absolute`ly positioned element and having that stretch to cover the screen.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style = {styles.backgroundContainer}>
    <Image source = {require('./img/landing-background.jpg')} resizeMode = 'cover' style = {styles.backdrop} />
  </View>
  <View style = {styles.overlay}>
    <Text style = {styles.headline}>It should appear in front of the Background Image</Text>
    <Image style = {styles.logo} source = {require('./img/logo.png')} />
  </View>
</View>

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  overlay: {
    opacity: 0.5,
    backgroundColor: '#000000'
  },
  logo: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    width: 160,
    height: 52
  },
  backdrop: {
    flex:1,
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
  headline: {
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    color: 'white'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 9):

I have the same issue, I used an `<ImageBackground>`

```
<View style={{height: 55,width: 55,justifyContent: 'center',alignItems: 'center'}}>

   <ImageBackground  source={{uri:this.state.image1}} style={{height: 50,width: 50}}>

            <View style={{flex: 1,justifyContent: 'flex-end',alignItems: 'flex-start'}}> //here you can change position of image with justifyContent and alignItems
                 <Image
                  source={ {uri:this.state.image2}}
                  style={{width: 20 , height: 20 ,alignItems: 'center',justifyContent: 'center',borderWidth: 1,borderColor: '#fff',borderRadius: 30}} />
            </View>

    </ImageBackground>

</View>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<ImageBackground style={{width:100, height:100, jsutifyContent:'center}}>
<Image/> //childimage
</ImageBackground
```

This would help you add a background image with an overlay of the child image, and worked perfectly fine for me.

Comment: i want to use image as header and over that i have to put back icon which is also an image so i tried to put header image in <imagebackground>. But when i give it a width 100% it's good but i also want to give it a height of 40% of screen but do not want to cut image to 40% what should i do?

Comment: You can adjust the height, width while specifying the style of the image. Just as above I gave the height and width as 100% you can specify yours accordingly.            E.g: <ImageBackground style={{height:100, width:100}}> <Image style={{height:40, width:40/> </ImageBackground>