# Why is this error in Image Component of React-Native?

Tags: image, react-native, layout, overlay

I would like to background black opacity.
I've wrote this code.

```
<Image source={require('../assets/images/test_img1.png')} style={[s.lastReviewImage]}>
  <View style={s.blackOverlay}/>
</Image>



lastReviewImage: {
    flex:1,
    width: null, height: null
  },
  blackOverlay: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    opacity: 0.3
  },
```

But, this is give me a error.

> Error: The Image component cannot contain children. if you want to render content on top of the image, consider using absolute positioning.

I know what this error means but I've surely set absolute property in blackOverlay.

I've refer this guides.

[Text Overlay Image with Darkened Opacity React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553174/text-overlay-image-with-darkened-opacity-react-native)

https://snack.expo.io/S15Lt3vjg

But, It's not working for me with the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to place an Image on top of other Image in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761012/how-to-place-an-image-on-top-of-other-image-in-react-native)

Comment: hi 문성수 , hope my answer (given below) helped you , feel free to upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set some background color or an image as the Screen Background, you need to use **ImageBackground** in place of **Image**.

```
 <ImageBackground
      source={yourSourceFile}
      style={s.blackOverlay}> 
        <....yourContent...>
    </ImageBackground>
```